# A movie where coffee acts like alcohol on aliens

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to work out the name of a Science Fiction movie from the 80's where the female alien ( in human form ) drinks coffee by mistake and gets very drunk. It's all I remember from the film but I seem to remember it was really enjoyable! Any ideas?

EDIT - I remember space and spaceship were involved too!

Comment: The title made me think of _MiB_, but...

Comment: Sounds similar to what happened in the movie "Cocoon - The Return"  however the female alien didn't get drunk from coffee, she ate shellfish that she called "bon appetite"

Comment: Another similar movie is "Alien Nation", where the aliens gets intoxicated by drinking sour milk.

Comment: Neither of those but thanks, I made an edit to the OP as I remembered some more!

Comment: A Google search pointed me to a somewhat obscure 1988 sci-fi TV miniseries called "Something Is Out There" about a police officer investigating a string of brutal murders. From what I read, his female alien ally Ta'Ra gets drunk on coffee.

Comment: That is the right answer, it was bundled into a movie I'm sure. Thanks vey much. So you answered this in a comment 15 hours ago @februaryInk and steve ruspo added an answer 12 hours ago so fairly the answer is yours! ( If you decide to add it )

Comment: Thank you, but please feel free to give it to Steve, @Leo. I've never seen or heard of the series before, and I commented with the hope that someone else could verify and make a full answer out of it.

Comment: Note that proposed duplicate target is the target of three other closed duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Something Is Out There](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134) was a mini-series on NBC in 1988.  It was then turned into a [TV-series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094551).

> *She brings her class and elegance to bear on the role here, her studious seriousness making for some appealing fish out of water comedy – especially amusing are the scenes with her **getting drunk on coffee***
>
> <sub><sup>[MoriaNZ Review](http://moria.co.nz/sciencefiction/something-is-out-there-1988.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Can you provide evidence where aliens "drunk on coffee" occurs?

Comment: http://moria.co.nz/sciencefiction/something-is-out-there-1988.htm   She brings her class and elegance to bear on the role here, her studious seriousness making for some appealing fish out of water comedy – especially amusing are _the scenes with her getting drunk on coffee_

Comment: You should [edit] that into the answer, not add to your answer in a comment.  The comments are not like a discussion forum; rather, it's review notes for you.  These comments can be deleted after you handle it.

Comment: @JDługosz - Or better yet, you could demonstrate to this new user how to improve their answers by editing them yourself. Show don't tell.

Comment: @Valorum that would not be better: **instruct**, don’t have it magically happen without his involvement.  Or do it for him if it’s been a week without adtion.  Many newcomers don’t realize that they *can* edit.

Comment: @JDługosz - I disagree entirely. They get a notification that it's been edited and can see (side-by-side) what's changed. Posting a message admonishing them isn't useful, especially when it would have taken you less time to just fix their post than it took to write a message *explaining how to fix their post*. You have an edit button too, and for good reason.

Comment: This was the one!! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 19):

This is probably *[The Stranger Within](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_Within)*, a 1974 American made-for-television science fiction horror film that premiered as the ABC Movie of the Week on October 1, 1974 and starring Barbara Eden and George Grizzard.

[image: The Stranger Within DVD cover]

### Plot Summary from Wikipedia

> Ann Collins (Eden), a painter, and her husband, David Collins (Grizzard), are expecting a baby. What confuses the couple is that David has had a vasectomy, and Ann is not supposed to be pregnant. Even though David suspects that Ann has been unfaithful to him, he stays with her. Because Ann had pregnancy troubles in the past that put her health at risk, David wants Ann to get an abortion, but every time the two try to go to get the procedure done, Ann experiences extreme labor pains and is unable to go through with the procedure.
>
> Throughout the course of her pregnancy, Ann has strange cravings for black coffee, raw meat and massive amounts of salt. She also exhibits personality and physical changes, including wanting to read books constantly, enduring freezing temperatures, developing acutely sensitive hearing, taking long and strenuous walks in the mountains, an inability to listen to other people, and healing her injuries within minutes.
>
> David wants Bob (David Doyle), a hypnotist, to see if he can obtain any information about why Ann is acting so strangely. Ann does not say a word, even when she is hypnotized. One day when Ann comes home from one of her walks in the mountains, she finds David, Bob, and Ann's friend Phyllis (Joyce Van Patten) waiting for her. She quickly drinks boiling hot coffee to catch her breath, and David notices that the coffee makes her drunk. Bob tries hypnotizing Ann again, and an extraterrestrial being starts speaking through her. The being says that his father banished him to this warm planet (Earth) and that he wants to go back to his home where it is "cool". He says that Ann was impregnated while she was painting in the mountains. After the alien stops talking through Ann, she finally falls asleep.
>
> During the night, Ann sneaks out to an abandoned house in the woods, where she gives birth. She walks into the woods, where many other women are also walking with their alien babies. David looks at one of Ann's paintings, depicting the alien being's home planet. The painting starts to smoke. David looks out the window and screams Ann's name, as he watches a spacecraft take Ann to the alien's home planet.

It fits your time period and features an alien who accidentally gets drunk on coffee.

### Trailer

Comment: Thank you for the wonderfully detailed answer! The only thing I forgot to mention it that there was a space & spaceship element. Either she found her way to Earth from it or something similar

Comment: @Leo: She does leave on the spaceship at the end. I added the rest of the summary from Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm confused now, you're right! It's doesn't seem to 'look' right. I'll watch it tonight and get back to you

Comment: You can find a few more scenes on Youtube, but not the complete film (there's complete versions of other movies with the same name, but not this tone). The hypnosis scene can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dYZTYJ_phI for example.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't it because they deleted the scene in the movie where they specify it but in Star Trek IV, the reason why Spock was acting so loopy is that he had eaten chocolate and was affected by the caffeine.  The novel keeps that scene.